# bootstrap fails due to a certificate mismatch

Tags: certificate, gnu-coreutils

When running `./bootstrap` in a freshly-cloned repository (https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils), it seems to either
not find some files it wants to or doesn't trust https://translationproject.org.

```sh
./bootstrap: Bootstrapping from checked-out coreutils sources...
./bootstrap: consider installing git-merge-changelog from gnulib
./bootstrap: getting gnulib files...
Submodule 'gnulib' (git://git.sv.gnu.org/gnulib.git) registered for path 'gnulib'
Cloning into '/home/vagrant/coreutils/gnulib'...
Submodule path 'gnulib': checked out '0ac98783691bbf8212537ebe18ddb68feb22a760'
./bootstrap: getting translations into po/.reference for coreutils...
ERROR: The certificate of 'translationproject.org' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'translationproject.org' has expired.
```

So what I am going to do to make the certificate be trusted by my system and make it compilatioin successfully?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think I have tried my best to clarify what I need. The only way you do not understand is that you do not have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get the certificate:

```bash
wget --mirror --level=1 -nd -v -A.po -P 'po/.reference' https://translationproject.org/latest/coreutils/
```

and then make the certificate trusted:

a) ask openssl to trust:

```bash
openssl s_client -connect translationproject.org:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

b) ask cert tool to trust

```bash
certtool --verbose --verify --infile=/tmp/translationproject.org.certs
```

Finally, you can use `./bootstrap` sucessfully.